No sound output on internal speakers or headphone jack in Linux, but Bluetooth sound works on HP Pavilion All-in-One
I'm running Linux on an HP Pavilion All-in-One 24-ca1xxx (6Z7J0EA#ABE), which also has Windows installed (but I don't use it). While the sound output on the internal speakers works fine under Windows, there is no sound output from either the internal speakers or the headphone jack under Linux. However, sound output via Bluetooth works perfectly.
Here is my hardware information:
$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path               Device          Class          Description
=================================================================
                                       system         HP Pavilion All-in-One 24-
/0                                     bus            89E9
/0/0                                   memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/28                                  memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/28/0                                memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchrono
/0/28/1                                memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchrono
/0/34                                  memory         288KiB L1 cache
/0/35                                  memory         192KiB L1 cache
/0/36                                  memory         7680KiB L2 cache
/0/37                                  memory         18MiB L3 cache
/0/38                                  processor      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM)
/0/100                                 bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                               bridge         12th Gen Core Processor PC
/0/100/1/0             /dev/fb0        display        TU117M [GeForce MX450]
/0/100/2               /dev/fb0        display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/4                               generic        Alder Lake Innovation Plat
/0/100/8                               generic        12th Gen Core Processor Ga
/0/100/a                               generic        Platform Monitoring Techno
/0/100/e                               storage        Volume Management Device N
/0/100/14                              bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0            usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/4          input4          input          Logitech Logi TKL Mechanic
/0/100/14/0/5          input6          input          USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/0/b                          multimedia     HP 5MP Camera
/0/100/14/0/c                          communication  Bluetooth Radio
/0/100/14/0/d                          input          HP 710 Wireless KB MS Comb
/0/100/14/1            usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/3          scsi6           storage        My Passport 264F
/0/100/14/1/3/0.0.0    /dev/sda        disk           1TB My Passport 264F
/0/100/14/1/3/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1       volume         931GiB data partition
/0/100/14/1/3/0.0.1                    generic        SES Device
/0/100/14.2                            memory         RAM memory
/0/100/16                              communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c                              bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0            enp2s0          network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Expr
/0/100/1c.7                            bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.7/0          wlp3s0          network        RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wi
/0/100/1f                              bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f/0                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/2                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                            input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/100/1f/4                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/5                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f.3            card0           multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.3/0          input13         input          HDA Intel PCH Mic
/0/100/1f.3/1          input14         input          HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/0/100/1f.3/2          input15         input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=
/0/100/1f.3/3          input16         input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=
/0/100/1f.3/4          input17         input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=
/0/100/1f.3/5          input18         input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=
/0/100/1f.4                            bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.5                            bus            Intel Corporation
/0/17                                  storage        Intel Corporation
/0/1d                                  generic        Intel Corporation
/0/1d.4                                bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/1d.4/0                              storage        SSD 660P Series
/1                                     power          Standard Efficiency
/2                     /dev/nvme0      storage        INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8H
/2/0                   hwmon1          disk           NVMe disk
/2/2                   /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
/2/1                   /dev/nvme0n1    disk           1024GB NVMe disk
/2/1/1                 /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         259MiB Windows FAT volume
/2/1/2                 /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         15MiB reserved partition
/2/1/3                 /dev/nvme0n1p3  volume         290GiB Windows NTFS volume
/2/1/4                 /dev/nvme0n1p4  volume         641MiB Windows NTFS volume
/2/1/5                 /dev/nvme0n1p5  volume         662GiB EXT4 volume
/3                     input0          input          Sleep Button
/4                     input1          input          Power Button
/5                     input10         input          HP WMI hotkeys
/6                     input11         input          Video Bus
/7                     input12         input          Video Bus
/8                     input2          input          Power Button
/9                     input3          input          AT Raw Set 2 keyboard
/a                     input7          input          Primax Electronics, Ltd HP
/b                     input8          input          Primax Electronics, Ltd HP
/c                     input9          input          Primax Electronics, Ltd HP

I am running the following Linux version and OEM kernel:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

$ uname -r
6.5.0-1025-oem

Here are the sound devices detected by the system:
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC274 Analog [ALC274 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Both pavucontrol and Alsa show all sliders at normal volume with no mute.
When I run a speaker test:
$ speaker-test -c 2 -t wav -D default

I see sound output activity in the PulseAudio volume control, but no sound is produced.
Additionally, PulseAudio seems to be stuck in suspend mode:
$ pactl list sinks short
51  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  PipeWire  s32le 2ch 

48000Hz  SUSPENDED

Running:
$ pulseaudio --start

does not change the SUSPEND state.
Here are the processes accessing the sound system:
$ fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  marcel     1169 F.... pipewire-media-
                     marcel     2660 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/seq:        marcel     1168 F.... pipewire

I can't fully disable or uninstall PipeWire or Pulseaudio, as this causes my system to hang (I've tried both).
Moreover, during boot, I see the following error messages:
[    0.177355] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dswload2-326)
[    0.177359] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
[    0.177362] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dswload2-326)
[    0.177366] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
[    1.784038] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[    1.784060] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 699645/43417600 files, 43231056/173666304 blocks
[    3.832724] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[    5.049921] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[    5.049966] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)

I can give the following information about my BIOS:
$ sudo dmidecode -t bios
[sudo] Passwort für marcel:
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.4.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: AMI
    Version: F.16
    Release Date: 08/22/2023
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
            PCI is supported
            PNP is supported
            BIOS is upgradeable
            BIOS shadowing is allowed
            Boot from CD is supported
            Selectable boot is supported
            EDD is supported
            BIOS boot specification is supported
            Function key-initiated network boot is supported
            Targeted content distribution is supported
            UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 15.22
    Firmware Revision: 1.22

Handle 0x004D, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 13
            en|US|iso8859-1
            fr|FR|iso8859-1
            es|ES|iso8859-1
            de|DE|iso8859-1
            it|IT|iso8859-1
            da|DK|iso8859-1
            fi|FI|iso8859-1
            nl|NL|iso8859-1
            no|NO|iso8859-1
            pt|PT|iso8859-1
            sv|SE|iso8859-1
            ja|JP|unicode
            zh|CN|unicode
    Currently Installed Language: de|DE|iso8859-1

I currently have Bodhi Linux installed, but I encountered the same issue with Linux Mint (Victoria). HP does not appear to offer Linux drivers for the internal sound card.
I've exhausted all ideas and could really use some help.

A newer kernel does not fix the problem
$ uname -r 6.8.0-40-generic
